# Magento 2 : How to get the best seller product collection?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7, magento2.3.0, best-seller

I'm trying to get Best Seller Product collection using below code, but it will not display any data

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setPeriod('yearly');
```

How to get Best Seller Product collection ?

Comment: it might not working because you have set "yearly" instead of "year", please check my ans for more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this code to get best seller product collections using objectManager.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory'); 
$collection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); 

$collection->setPeriod('year');
//$collection->setPeriod('month');
//$collection->setPeriod('day');

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

Comment: Hi Aasim Goriya I have used same logic in my custom block but it is displaying empty records (those are not available currently at admin end products grid) could you please advise?

Comment: Exclude empty records using filters at code level

Comment: @AssimGoriya, How can i get latest month's best seller product? any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

But if you want latest bestselling product collection for the day please use this code in block

```
public function getBestsellerProduct(){

$resourceCollection = $this->_resourceFactory->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection');   
$resourceCollection->setPageSize(6);
$resourceCollection->setPeriod('day')->addStoreFilter(1)->getSelect()->order('period DESC');
return $resourceCollection;

}
```

Comment: same for latest month's best seller product instead of 'day' replace it by 'month'